# when file/folder renamed, git removes and adds them (vscode)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I rename file at vscode, as you can see at below picture, it deletes and creates new file. So I lost the git history for file. Is it normal behaviour? It is not like that in webstorm.
[image]

Comment: You are not losing anything. It's normal.

Comment: It's normal behavior... git **does not** track renames (keep in mind that git only keeps the snapshot of the project in commits plus parents commits which is how it can _then_ calculate what changes between commits... on the fly, when you run `git diff`, for example). It's not like you _lost_ history of the file. You can still ask git to try harder if you run `git log --follow`

Comment: thanks everyone I just figureed it out. I am using this vscode only for a few days so I confused a lot...